# Ellipsis of verbs in a series of adjectives and participles

Tags: ellipsis

Can I leave out the second *was*?

> 1- The little animal was alert and quiet but **was** caught
>   nonetheless.
>
> 2- The little animal was alert and quiet but caught nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you leave out the second **was**, it sounds like the little animal caught some other animal.

It may help to think about this scenario in the present tense:

> 1 - The little animal is alert and quiet but gets caught nonetheless.
>
> 2 - The little animal is alert and quiet but catches nonetheless.

2 doesn't really make sense, since it doesn't mention what the little animal catches.

Comment: Thanks tjp. I understand the analogy is meant to illustrate an idea by a similar example. One could say: how about:*The little animal is alert and quiet but caught nonetheless*. I admit your examples made me reconsider my writing.